# How to constrain type of object keys to namespace constants?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, mapped-types

I would like to define a mapped type whose keys are the values of all constants under a namespace.

I wasn't able to find other questions that cover this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894121/using-namespace-constants-as-object-keys) and its duplicate talk about JavaScript, whereas I'm looking to strongly type the property of a class. I also couldn't find a reference in the [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html).

Description:

I have a namespace as such:

```
export namespace Controls {
    export const Foo = "foo";
    export const Bar = "bar";
    export const Baz = "baz";
    // ... a dozen others
}
```

This namespace contains nothing else. Only those exported `const`s.

I would like to define an object type to express the following meaning: "this object keys can only be const values declared in that namespace". Naively something like:

`type Namespaced = { [K in Controls]?: ControlDelegate }`

The above doesn't compile because I can't use a namespace as a type. Indexing the type also doesn't work for the same reason:

`type NamespaceKeys = Controls[keyof typeof Controls]`

Then I had this epiphany to use:

`{ [K in keyof typeof Controls]?: ControlDelegate }`

which does compile, and the resolved type looks like what I want, however I'm then unable to instantiate literals:

```
this.controlDelegates = {
            [Controls.Foo]: new FooControlDelegate() // it implements ControlDelegate
        }
```

with the following compile error:

`Type '{ "foo": FooControlDelegate; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly Foo?: ControlDelegate; ... Object literal may only specify known properties`

What's the correct way to constrain the type of object keys to the values under a certain namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keyof typeof Controls` gives you the *keys* of `Controls`, which are "Foo", "Bar", "Baz". What you want are the *values* of `Controls` which are "foo", "bar", "baz" (lowercase).

You can achieve this with `typeof Controls[keyof typeof Controls]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cdimitroulas advice, I ended up declaring the property as:

```
controlDelegates: { [K in typeof Controls[keyof typeof Controls]]?: ControlsDelegate }
```

which can then be properly initialized as:

```
     this.controlDelegates = {
         [Controls.Foo]: new FooControlDelegate()
     }
```

However this approach won't scale. The next time something gets added to the namespace, if that something has a type not assignable to object keys — e.g. a class — the typing will break.

Since the namespace only contains string constants, a more future-proof solution is to just convert it to an `enum`:

```
export enum Controls {
    FOO = "foo";
    BAR = "bar";
    BAZ = "baz";
    // ... and so on
}
```